# Replace None value with empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a JSON file that contains a value of None for some attributes.  I want to convert this value to a strings ("None").  Here is one example:

```
Convert
{"id": 134768, "groupId": 9039, "vehicleId": None, "username": "ccrabtree"}
to
{"id": 134768, "groupId": 9039, "vehicleId": "None", "username": "ccrabtree"}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map function as below to call a method say "replace_none" for every key in the dictionary and replace None with "None"

```
def replace_none(key):
    if d.get(key) is None:
       d[key] = "None"
map(replace_none,d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension for this:

```
new_dict = {key: 'None' if value is None else value for (key, value) in old_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simply looping through the dictionary:

```
import json
dictionary = json.load(open( "FILENAME HERE", 'r'))
for k in dictionary:
    if dictionary[k] is None:
        dictionary[k] = "None"
```

Also should be noted that the empty string is not `"None"` it is `""`.

Comment: `None` is not a value per se, and should be compared using the identity operator `is` instead : `if dic[key] is None: ...` Not a big change, but cleaner.